# How to use node-module 'Validator' in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation

I have installed and imported validator module in the node js file.

I want to validate the User's phone number using npm module "Validator" I have written the code as below but it is **Not Working**. It is inside of the schema

```
phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique:true,
    validate(value) {
      if(!validator.isMobilePhone(value)){
        throw new error ("Please enter valid phone number")
    }
  }
```

It is saving all the invalid phone numbers as well like jist : 1234.

How to solve this?

Comment: what all do you want to validate?

Comment: @sid sorry?? I didn't understand your question

Comment: what parameters do you want to validate for a phone number?

Comment: @sid How much parameters are there in a phone number?

Comment: I recommend you to use decent npm packages with documentations like Joi.

Comment: country code, length depending on country.

Comment: does validator validate only strings. havent used before

Comment: @cmgchess don't know. maybe.

Comment: @sid both parameters?

Answer (score 0):

you have to install this dependencie
$ npm install --save validator

Comment: I suggest to give further details. OP is asking how to use something specific and your answer seems to suggests to install something.